# Python: parallelizing any/all statements

Tags: python, performance, parallel-processing

I am running some Python program and I've noticed that the bottleneck is in the line doing the following

```py
all(foo(s) for s in l)
```

what I am wondering is - what would be the best way to make this into a parallel computation? foo(s) is a thread safe method inspecting s and returning True/False with respect to some criteria. No data structure is changed by foo.

So the question is

> How to test in parallel if all elements of a list l have property foo
>   , exiting as soon as one element of l does not satisfy foo?

Edit. Adding more context. I do not know what kind of context you are looking for but in my scenario s is a graph and foo(s) computes some graph theoretical invariant (for example average distance or perhaps something similar)

Comment: there is not enough context for this imho ...

Comment: Without more context, the best suggestion I could give would be to use the multiprocessing module with a pool of workers. However, if foo() isn't a "fat" enough function then the speed up will be minimal (if at all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will sort of depend on what `foo(s)` is doing.  If it is I/O bound, waiting on blocking calls, than just using threads will help.  The easiest way is to create a pool of threads and use `pool.map`:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool(10)
all(pool.map(foo, l))
```

If, however, the function is cpu bound, using a lot of processor power, this will not help you.  Instead you need to use the multiprocessing pool:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(4)
all(pool.map(foo, l))
```

This will use separate processes instead of threads, allowing multiple cpu cores to be used.  If your function `foo` is very quick, though, the overhead will eliminate any advantage of parallel processing, so you need to test to make sure you get the results you expect

see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers

**EDIT:**
I've assumed you're using Python 2.7.x.  If you're using Python3 you have more advanced concurrency features in [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#module-concurrent.futures).  Including `ThreadPoolExecutor` and `ProcessPoolExecutor`.

I would recommend using those for parallel processing and the [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) lib for I/O bound problems.

Answer (score 0):

Python comes with the  `multiprocessing` module; there's an [example](http://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/mapreduce.html) implementing a classical `reduce` algorithm (which could be used to implement `all`). Generally, you might want to look at [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) functionality:

> The Pool class represents a pool of worker processes. It has methods which allows tasks to be offloaded to the worker processes in a few different ways.